# html Form not recognized in my jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jsp

I have a JSP page which is included in the main page..Within the JSP page, I have given a HTMLform which I want to submit() once the user clicks it using Jquery?

```
<form id="orderBean1" name="myForm" action="/Auto/Item" method="post">
            <input id="filename" name="filename" value="" />
        </form>
```

First,

Suprisingly, this form is not recognized within the page..

When I give  $('#orderBean1') in my console it does not give the form object whereas $('#filename') gives me the filename input element.

Second ,
As the form is not recognized it does not get submitted...

```
$("#vehreport").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();(I have given this stmt even after the submit() and still not working...

        $("#orderBean1").submit();

        alert("formsubmnittted");
    })
```

Question -
Why doesn't the form element is recognized in my page?

Answer (score 0):

I set up a JSbin [here](http://jsbin.com/rozihozodu/1/edit?js,console,output).

As you can see, `#orderbean1` is recognized, and submits.

The error is likely elsewhere is your JS or markup, though if I'm misunderstanding the question please clarify

Comment: Thanks..The problem is elsewhere..I had a form within a form and that was the problem...